# What does “fligh” mean?

Tags: meaning

It is probably a type-o as “flight” makes perfect sense here. But this book is full of interesting little words and thought maybe it’s an obscure little synonym (or maybe and old school—or olde English—version of it)?[image]

Anthony Nutting, Scramble for Africa, Paperback edition 1994, p 19.

Comment: Yes it's a typo (NB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *fligh* seems to be a misspelling/misprinting of *flight*. This work by Mr Nutting does not seem to employ any archaic/obsolete spellings of any word.

Although the *Oxford English Dictionary* lists *fligh* as a now-obsolete variant spelling of the verb *fly* sometimes found in Old English, it does not seem relevant here. There is no other word in the excerpt that is not 20th century English spelling.